# C# - IoC - Autofac Dependency Injection on WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I am having some trouble configuring Autofac with my application. I would appreciate all of your help. Below is the code with the exception. Should you need more details please don't hesitate to comment. Thanks!

1. Api Config

   ```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       // Web API configuration and services
       var setings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
       setings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
       setings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

       // Web API Cors
       var origin = "https://localhost:44381";
       EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origin, "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(cors);

       // DI
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

       builder.RegisterType<AlertRepository>()
           .As<IAlertRepository>();
       builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
           .As<IUnitOfWork>();
       builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
           .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
           .InstancePerRequest();
       builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

       var container = builder.Build();
       GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

       // Web API routes
       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
   }
   ```
2. Unit of Work Class

   ```
   public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
   {
           private readonly CRNetContext _context;

           public UnitOfWork(CRNetContext context)
           {
               _context = context;
               Alerts = new AlertRepository(_context);
           }

           public IAlertRepository Alerts { get; private set; }

           public int Complete()
           {
               return _context.SaveChanges();
           }

           public void Dispose()
           {
               _context.Dispose();
           }
   }
   ```
3. Exception

> {
>     "message": "An error has occurred.",
>     "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AlertsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
>     "exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
>     "stackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()",
>     "innerException": {
>       "message": "An error has occurred.",
>       "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = AlertsController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [CRNET.API.Controllers.AlertsController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = UnitOfWork (ReflectionActivator), Services = [CRNET.DAL.Persistance.IUnitOfWork], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'CRNET.DAL.Persistance.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext)'. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)",
>       "exceptionType": "Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException",
>       "stackTrace": "   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)\r\n   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)\r\n   at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) in C:\projects\autofac-webapi\src\Autofac.Integration.WebApi\AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.cs:line 76\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)",
>       "innerException": {
>         "message": "An error has occurred.",
>         "exceptionMessage": "An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = UnitOfWork (ReflectionActivator), Services = [CRNET.DAL.Persistance.IUnitOfWork], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'CRNET.DAL.Persistance.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext)'. (See inner exception for details.)",
>         "exceptionType": "Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException",
>         "stackTrace": "   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__5_0()\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)",
>         "innerException": {
>           "message": "An error has occurred.",
>           "exceptionMessage": "None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'CRNET.DAL.Persistance.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext)'.",
>           "exceptionType": "Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException",
>           "stackTrace": "   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.GetValidConstructorBindings(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot resolve parameter 'CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext context'...

You never register the type `CRNetContext` with Autofac. To fix it add:

```
builder.RegisterType<CRNET.DAL.Models.CRNetContext>().AsSelf();
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. Spent all day on this. Overlooked that message.